# Change where Bin folder is created

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to ASP# and working on a project in Visual Studio 2015. I'm trying to publish a website, but I do not want the Bin folder to be created on root, using a different path `webservice/bin` instead.

Currently, once published, the Bin folder contains both my dlls and a Newtonsoft package installed trough NuGet. How can I configure my project so Bin folder is a different path when publishing and testing? Thanks!

Comment: How are you publishing? Web deploy? file system?

Comment: File System. The problem is that I need to set up the project so it always publish the same way, and moving the Bin folder outside "root" is a requeriment from the production set up guys.

Comment: If you unload the project and look at the xml, have you tried changing the <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165410.aspx

Comment: Changing this path doesn't seems to affect the published project, while I can see the webservice/bin folder created in the solution explorer, the published files still have the standard bin/ structure.